# Signing Identity and provisioning profiles are not visible in visual studio 2019 or 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

I have been struggling to publish my second xamarin forms application on App store for 5 days, and It should be published 3 days ago.

The current situation is:

I have one development certificate and one distribution certificate
I have two App Identities ( App1 & App2)
I have four (4) provisioning profiles ( 1 dev and 1 dist for each app )

Signing Identities and provisioning profiles are not visible on vs 2017 nor 2019, although they are visible on xcode

Before, I had only one application registered on the apple portal and I can see the singing identities and its profiles, but when I added the new application and added its new provisioning profiles to Xcode, They are not available on visual studio, so I removed all old certificates (development and distribution) and all provisioning profiles from Apple developer portal and from Xcode (~/Library/MobileDevices/) for each application, and cleared everything and started from scratch, and did it all again but no hope, neither the first app or the second one.

Any help please!

Comment: Is that mean if you use a lower version of Xamarin.iOS, then you can see the provisioning profiles in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Do you add your Apple account to your Visual Studio?
To add Account in Visual Studio, following this in Visual Studio:

> Tools -> Options -> Xamarin ->Apple Accounts.

Try it. Maybe it help you.

Comment: I did, but it didn't help anything

Comment: Hi, I fixed by update Visual Studio to newest version. Go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin ->Apple Accounts. Sign in, after that click in table in the bottom, select account -> view certificate. In that UI, you can create new Signin Identity or dowload all provision (If you have apple develop account).
Note: Remeber match bundle ID with your app in visual and bundle ID in Apple portal. If not match, No Signin Identity/provision visible

Answer (score 0):

You need to download your provisioning profiles to xcode before seeing them in visual studio:

1. First go to preferences in Xcode
2. Then download manual profiles

[image]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos

Comment: I did that, the profiles are already exit in Xcode but not in vs 2019, the problem occurred only on that latest version of xamarin.ios